# How to override resource file defined in a Jar?

Tags: java, internationalization, overriding, resource-file

In a file structure of standard J2EE Web application, I want to override a key-value message pair that defined in a resource file that reside in an imported Jar. I know that I need to create a resource file with the same name of which I want to override, But where should I put the file in my web application so that the message key defined in my resource file will override that of same key defined in the resource file in Jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<application dir>/WEB-INF/classes/path/of/the/resource/to/override`